# Append a vector as a row in a CSV file

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

#### What I already have:

Consider the following data — just dummy data, the real data is created automatically:

```
features <- numeric(0)
features <- c(features, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
features2 <- numeric(0)
features2 <- c(features2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
featureVectors <- list()
featureVectors[["file1"]] <- features
featureVectors[["file2"]] <- features2
resultMatrix <- do.call(rbind, featureVectors)
colnames(resultMatrix) <- c("SPEC_MEAN", "SPEC_SD", "SPEC_MODE", "AUTOC_MEAN", "AUTOC_SD", "ZC_MEAN")
```

This produces an output like the following:

```
      SPEC_MEAN SPEC_SD SPEC_MODE AUTOC_MEAN AUTOC_SD ZC_MEAN
file1         1       2         3          4        5       6
file2         1       2         3          4        5       6
```

I can write this to a CSV file by calling `write.csv(resultMatrix, file="out.csv")`.

---

#### What I need:

As the result file is (currently) just created on the fly, I'd like to write these `features` (i.e. the vectors) to the CSV file as soon they are evaluated.

So I thought I'd use `write.csv` and `append`, but the option isn't available for the method. I then thought I could use `write.table`, but there are two problems:

1. `write.table` does not indent the first empty column name, thus leaving my first row shifted one to the left.
2. The data is somehow incorrectly transposed. See example below.

---

#### What I've tried:

Also, calling these commands …

```
write.table(resultMatrix, file="data-appended.csv", sep=",")
write.table(features, file="data-appended.csv", sep=",", append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE)
```

… produces this result:

```
"SPEC_MEAN","SPEC_SD","SPEC_MODE","AUTOC_MEAN","AUTOC_SD","ZC_MEAN"
"file1",1,2,3,4,5,6
"file2",1,2,3,4,5,6
"1",1
"2",2
"3",3
"4",4
"5",5
"6",6
```

… which is not what I want. So, how do I append the content of the `features` vector, including the `file` name, to an already existing CSV file?

Comment: What's the type of the `resultMatrix` as R sees it?

Comment: `typeof(resultMatrix) => [1] "double"`. Does it matter, here? I'd just like to write the new `feature` vectors to the file, i.e. doesn't matter if there's the `resultMatrix` variable.

Comment: Sorry I was actually looking for output of class(resultMatrix). :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two adjustments will solve your two problems.

- To keep indentation of the column headers, use the unintuitive (but documented!) argument `col.names=NA`:

  ```
  write.table(resultMatrix, file = "data-appended.csv", sep = ",", 
              col.names = NA)
  ```
- To write `features` (a vector) as a row rather than a column, transpose it and convert it to a matrix before passing it to `write.table()`:

  ```
  FF <- as.matrix(t(features))
  write.table(FF, file = "data-appended.csv", sep = ",", 
              col.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
  ```

Comment: So, is there any easier method to setting the `file` than: `rownames(FF) = fileName` to get `file1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`?

Comment: Not really.  I think that's the proper way to do this.  In response to the earlier incarnation of your comment, you could also use something like the following to create the first header line of the file:  `writeLines(c("", colnames(resultMatrix)), con = "data-appended.csv", sep = ",")`.